# Can I see a user's deleted questions?

Tags: support, down-votes, deleted-questions

Is there a way for me to see all question by a user that have been deleted? I'm pretty sure I downvoted a question today, which was then reposted with more info, and I can't find the original on the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete).

I suspect, but cannot prove, that the poster of that question has been downvoting [a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769229/how-will-exit-behave-in-a-c-program), since they also echoed my comment "What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?" I can't see my original comment in my activity log, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devs, moderators and users with 10k rep or more can see deleted posts.

One single downvote can't really be construed as revenge downvoting. If there was a track record of uncharacteristic downvoting then flag it. The system also has some compensation mechanisms to protect users against down voting "sprees".

Shog's answer to this question probably sums things up best:

> [What does I do when I think someone downvotes because of jealousy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67586/what-does-i-do-when-i-think-someone-downvotes-because-of-jealousy/67619#67619)

Answer (score 3):

Normal users cannot specifically sift out the deleted posts of a specific user. They can see deleted posts, but only moderators and devs have the ability to specifically view a particular user and their deleted post history.