# Seeking feedback on downvoted question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvoted-questions

I am trying to improve my skill at asking questions, so I would like to ask feedback on a question I asked that was downvoted.

[Force child class to override function of ancestor via parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791178/force-child-class-to-override-function-of-ancestor-via-parent)

Why do you think I got downvoted?

Comment: I can only guess, but how does it show research effort? Also, first comment is a request for clarification and I don't see your question edited.

Comment: And BTW it is just 1 downvote.

Comment: It might be the fact that the question does not show much research effort indeed, I will think about that next time, same for editing. I just did not expect to be downvoted.

Comment: [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791178/force-child-class-to-override-function-of-ancestor-via-parent#comment29419311_19791178) might shed some light. (Not saying its author is the downvoter)

Comment: Well, read a tooltip on downvote button ;) "... does not show any research effort; it's unclear ..." - both apply, or at least someone could think they do.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys, I will try to improve this.

Comment: [Broadly applicable advice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-down-voted-how-should-i-react), not specifically related to your post. And a +1 for looking to improve!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, voting is anonymous, so I can only speculate, but the tooltip for the downvote button says

> This question doesn't show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Well, the question is clear, and it's arguably useful to others, so I can only imagine that the downvoter either thinks that the question doesn't demonstrate research effort, or they downvoted for some other unknown reason, like they didn't get enough sleep the night before.

I personally think there's nothing at all wrong with your question.  Folks who require research effort on questions like this assume that such a thing is easy to research (because they already know it), and it's not like you're asking anyone to write your program for you.

Note that the downvote is the only negative feedback on your question; there are no close votes, no flags, an answer with a score of six, and a few folks engaging in the question via comments learned something new today.  Not bad at all.