# Clicking site proposal link in Area 51 discussion crashes the Android SE app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51, android-app

When accessing a discussion on Area 51 through SE app by [direct link to discuss.area51.se](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21596/51707), clicking the site proposal link crashes the app.

[image: discuss.area51.se on SE app]

[image: app crashed]

Comment: Did this only happen once? Does still happen if you close the app and clear history/cache (if possible) etc, and re-load the app and try again?

Comment: @James I don't have the Android device on me. It did crash each time I tried (3 trials), but I didn't clear the cache. I guess the app got reloaded since it crashed :) Is it working on your side?

Comment: downvoter/closer: what is unclear in the question?

Comment: I don't use the app myself, I just wondered if this was perhaps a *one off* issue. And I have no idea of the downvote, and also someone's flagged as "unclear what you're asking". Your question seems fine to me, I understood the problem in about 3 seconds.

Comment: Could you mention the app version? On v1.0.73 (beta), the `discuss.area51.se` cannot be browsable in SE app anymore, which probably make this bug obsolete. Furthermore, `discuss.area51.se` is not supported by SE app (as can be seen by "Unknown Site"), so this is a two-fold bug. As for why it crashed, AFAIK, the SE app tries to open the proposal in the app, but fails miserably as it's not a proper Q&A site.

Comment: @AndrewT. Indeed now no more browsable.Was previous version.

Comment: As for the reason why it's being downvoted and vote as unclear... I believe because there is not enough information (including the most important one: app version). I could improve the question if you permit it...

Comment: Closing since I can no longer reproduce this bug.  Opening the link opens the question in a web view.