# Which site is appropriate for me to ask about textbooks?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have jumped to a couple of sites asking for the answers to the multiple-choice questions of the [APUSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP_United_States_History) Amsco textbook("AMSCO Advanced Placement Edition: United States History, Newman, John J., and John M. Schmalbach") , or a textbook site in general. Many people just downvoted and didn't give me an indicator as to where I should ask. Where can I post it?

Edit: Pdf to the aforementioned book https://ma.lvlhs.org/ourpages/auto/2012/4/12/58446259/TOP%20REVIEW%20TEXTBOOK.pdf

Comment: There is no site that will recommend a textbook for you. Some sites might recommend a textbook on their topic. What subject are you planning to ask about?

Comment: Asking for the answers to multiple choice questions from a textbook, and asking about a textbook site in general, are different things. What *specific* question(s) do you plan to ask? Do you have an example question?

Comment: Specifically about Ap Us History, Amsco textbook. Sorry if that wasn't clear

I am trying to find a place for that specific book's multiple choice questions, not sure if that would be under a textbook channel or sort.

So a specific question: "Answers to the AMSCO Ap United States History Multiple Choice questions"

Comment: The textbook isn't really relevant except insofar as you're intending to plagiarise its questions then? Why not ask about the topics in the textbook you don't understand in your own words?

Comment: There are multiple choice questions in the book and all I a wondering is if there is a website or link that provides me the letter answers

Comment: There's no site that will provide you links like that as answers I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the help, but why are people downvoting again? Does this question violate anything? You just downvote and leave without a comment?

Comment: See [I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121350/289691)

Comment: In what way will it help you or anyone else in anything other than the very short term to have a list of multiple choice answers with no explanation?

Comment: That was a challenge for the search engines! APUSH = *[Advanced Placement United States History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP_United_States_History)* (AKA *AP United States History*). AP = [Advanced Placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Placement), *not* [Associated Press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Press).

Comment: What is *"Amsco"*? The publisher, *"Amsco School Publications"*? And the combination *"APUSH Amsco"* = the ***particular*** textbook *"[AMSCO Advanced Placement Edition: United States History, Newman, John J., and John M. Schmalbach](https://fiveable.me/apush/-/best-ap-us-history-textbook/blog/MUH02htqBzztuzv3L4lg)"*?

Comment: Yes, that book. Funny, searching up APUSH right on search engine leads straight to Advanced Placement United States History

Comment: The answers are in the book, in so much as you have to study the relevant period of history. Read the chapters, visit History.com and you might learn something new. Memorizing answers is not the same as understanding.

Comment: Searching the title of this book together with "answer key" gives [plenty of results](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=answer+key+AMSCO+Advanced+Placement+Edition%3A+United+States+History) on your favourite search engine.

Comment: @Mari-LouA they are in the book? Page number? I have the answers but I just need a source to double check. Obviously I have done them already.

Answer (score 9):

> There are multiple choice questions in the book and all I a wondering is if there is a website or link that provides me the letter answers

There is no such site in the Stack Exchange network. And there won't be. Stack Exchange was built so you can have experts answer your questions, that you still have despite having researched your question on your own.

Wanting to know a multiple choice answer without reading the textbook it's contained in is the anti-thesis of Stack Exchange's model. It's purposefully avoiding the research that would be trivial because the research material is limited and readily available (assuming you have a copy of the text book), in favor of just asking for the answer.

**If** you have actually *read* the textbook, and still find the multiple choice question confusing and have an *actual history question*, then feel free to visit https://history.stackexchange.com/ and ask your question. About history, not about a textbook.

That said, I think you gathered many downvotes because you just assumed that everybody knows what you were talking about. We are "the global internet", not your 5 local schoolyard buddies. We have no idea what US textbook you are talking about when you use all the abbreviations you take for granted. I think your question would have been closed with a lot less downvotes if you had *explained* to the global audience what you were talking about, instead of throwing out a number of abbreviations only known to a very constrained local audience. At first glance, I did not even know your history question was off topic, because I couldn't even *understand* what you were asking.

Comment: So abbreviations... my fault. Still new to this site. However, my intention was not to "skip work", I read the book, readily available online as a pdf (https://ma.lvlhs.org/ourpages/auto/2012/4/12/58446259/TOP%20REVIEW%20TEXTBOOK.pdf)
And despite reading and understanding the text, all I am asking for is a way to check my answers, the process of learning. That's it.