# Response to a moderator on a Stack Exchange site

Tags: discussion, edits, moderators

I got an edit by a moderator (https://chinese.stackexchange.com/posts/50585/revisions) and would like to respond without distracting others' focus on questions/answers. How can I do so?

Comment: Rather than doing that, maybe read [this instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Comment: Thanks. It certainly helps, but the link does not address some specific questions I have about the moderator's edit, e.g., she said " Serial downvoting is automatically reversed" and I'd like to learn more about this.

Comment: OK, well that's [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). You could always search for these kind of answers yourself though.

Comment: I'd also recommend reading [I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121351/377214) for advice as to how you should react the next time your post is downvoted. (In summary, your actions here weren't correct.)

Comment: I was searching and ended up with the exact page you provided. So it seems that the search of SE is reasonably good. And certainly thank you for providing the link.

Comment: I initially DV'd this question after reading the revision you wanted to contact the moderator about, but based on the respectful interactions and what seems to be a good-faith attempt to understand the rules leading to the post, I decided to remove the vote (and I rarely comment about doing so) - way to go, nice to see this from time to time.

Comment: @OlegValter thanks for the additional explanation. It certainly made new users feel more welcomed.

Answer (score 22):

There's nothing really to do. You edited some meta commentary about 'malicious' downvoting, the moderator really rolled it back explaining we have tools to deal with it if there's a pattern.

Any experienced user could and would have done so, not just a moderator. I would refer you to the  [expected behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) section of the help center - under no chitchat. Folks might downvote your post for complaining about downvotes too so the moderator was being helpful.

Comment: thanks. It's not exactly addressing my questions but is certainly helpful.

Comment: Well the answer is you don't! And there is also no need for it, mods don't always want to be bothered about simple things like this. @ALife

Comment: Sure. I've inferred that from other helpful comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That was my edit (I use my Chinese name at Chinese.SE).

> ...would like to respond without distracting others' focus on questions/answers. How can I do so?

I guess I was unspecific in my comment, but I meant bring it up at [Chinese.SE Meta](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Comment: Thanks for responding here. I did not know the existence of a Chinese.SE Meta and am glad to know and will post there if needed. For now I believe I've got what I wanted to know. Thank you for your efforts making the site healthy.