# Cannot post comments on SE app on iOS

Tags: support, ios-app

Although I can post fine from my desktop, on iOS I am unable to post comments (haven't tried an answer) on the SE app.

"Request failed. Could not perform this request with your account. Please try logging back in. If this persists, let us know on meta."

Here I am. Anyone else having issues?

Comment: The apps have been delisted and unsupported for years. They are almost guaranteed to totally break up in the next few months.

Comment: @TedShifrin This is possibly related to the recent (also currently featured) [Mobile app infrastructure being decommissioned](/q/383026).

Comment: Thanks @JohnOmielan. This is the first issue I've encountered. I've been using the apps heavily for years and years. Too bad there's no way of informing those of us who are ignorant :) I am not sure why this warrants a downvote ... but there we are.

Comment: They could [use the old feed to notify app users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383119/323179) (but they didn't).

Comment: I'm with you Ted, I use the app every day.  I am dismayed it won't work anymore. I find the site through phone browsers to be unsatisfying.

Comment: [*"**Your post does not show enough research effort**
This is one of the things mentioned when you hover over the downvote arrow, and this is probably is the most frequent reason for downvotes on questions."*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react)

Comment: The iOS app was built so good that it can't even die naturally, they have to perform actions to help it die. It's like a car that can still drive after 50 years, without needing spare parts.

Comment: @Nij With respect, I would say that the  "error message" I was given was misleading and could certainly have been more informative. At any rate, "let us know on meta" should not result in a spanking.

Comment: The error message being given is itself an error. The app is totally unsupported, including any corrections to the banners and messages it sends. They may or may not be legitimate, and you use it entirely at your own cost and risk and efficacy.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard And this change is equivalent to discontinuing the sale of the fuel required for it to run. (E.g., the discontinuation of leaded gasoline.)

Comment: @Sonic fuel can be stashed, people still use the app and report bugs. :)

Answer (score 8):

As of today, the registrations on Stack Apps for all our prior apps were disabled. This state also disables [write access](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write) for them, which effectively makes all the apps read-only now.

This is one step being taken as part of [our decommissioning of the mobile app infrastructure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026).

Comment: Interesting - I keep an old access token (tied to the official Android app) around, and it still works for uploading images and editing posts. I also have an iOS one which doesn't work anymore - when I use it, it says "Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write". I can't find that post, though, even when searching for deleted questions :P