# Stack Exchange iOS app removed from the AppStore. Is there an IPA file?

Tags: discussion, ios-app

After the **Stack Overflow** app was removed from the App Store a long time ago, I recently realized that the **Stack Exchange** iOS app was removed too and I could't reinstall it on my new iPhone.

It seems [there isn't any plan to resubmit the native app to the App Store again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/mobile-app-infrastructure-being-decommissioned).

So is there somewhere to download the [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa) file, so I can install it directly on my device?

Or even the source code, so I can build it from scratch?

Comment: The apps will stop working soon, since all the API support for them is being dropped. Even if you install the app, it won't work for long anyway.

Comment: Worth a shot for short term use anyway

Comment: No, it's not. What is so wonderful about the app that you insist on having it?

Comment: For easier access. I’m very active in SO but the iOS safari can not get together all information I usually use, at once

Comment: It would be nice if downvoters explain themselves instead of hit-and-run. Thanks 

Comment: While I didn't downvote - there's literally a post on the right saying the back end of the app is being removed, and there's mentions of the app being degraded. I do feel like this could count as lack of research effort.

Comment: Regarding the source code: [Make the mobile apps open source!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315791/241919) was declined.

Answer (score 16):

The iOS app was intentionally [delisted over a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363043) to prevent users from installing an unmaintained app. Even if you found some place that has the files available for you to manually install it, there's no good reason to do so at this point.

As mentioned in the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/mobile-app-infrastructure-being-decommissioned), all the mobile app infrastructure is being removed and the app, even if you manage to install it the hard way, **will stop working completely**. The app registrations have [already been disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383238/cannot-post-comments-on-se-app-on-ios) which means they are read-only and can no longer be used to participate on the sites. They will only continue to break further in the coming weeks. You should not be installing it fresh on new devices.